# Regex only one alternation

Tags: regex

Regex: `(simple|complex)`
Text: `using simple with key value pairs using complex with key value pairs using simple with key value pairs`

Is there any way to match only once the `simple` value if it's used and not two times?

Comment: don't use the global modifier, or `^(?:(?!\bsimple\b|\bcomplex\b).)*\K(?:simple|complex)`  https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/3

Comment: could you explain this `Is there any way to match only once the simple value if it's used and not two times?`

Comment: Are you saying that in order to successfully match, the string must have only one occurrence of `simple` and only one occurrence of `complex`? If so you can use: `^(?=(?:(?!simple).)*?(?:simple)(?:(?!simple).)*$)(?=^(?:(?!complex).)*?(?:complex)(?:(?!complex).)*$).*?$`

Comment: What I want is if it finds simple then it should match only one time or if it finds complex it should match it only one time and if it finds simple and complex it should match them only one time.

Comment: Simply use 2 separate matches without the global flag?

Comment: @AvinashRaj If I don't use the global modifier then it won't find complex

Comment: please consider the answer I have given below.  Are the outputs correct for all the example strings I have given?

Comment: @Vorsprung I was looking for an expression, not a script :) I could have done it with a script also :) but thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use Data::Dumper;

my @ex=qw(simple complex simplycomplex complexcomplexbutsimple simplebutcomplex);

sub runexamples {
  my $qr=shift;
  my @matches;
  for my $example (@ex) {
    push @matches, [($example =~ /$qr/)];
  }
  return \@matches;
}

print Dumper(runexamples(qr/(complex|simple)/));
```

this program if run produces the following output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'simple'
          ],
          [
            'complex'
          ],
          [
            'complex'
          ],
          [
            'complex'
          ],
          [
            'simple'
          ]
        ];
```

The global modifier is not set and both "complex" and "simple" are detected correctly.  If the first string is "simple" then that is reported on it's own even if the string "complex" is also present.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will only match lines that have either `simple` or `complex` in them but only if either appears only once:

`^(?=(?:(?!simple).)*?(?:(?:simple)(?:(?!simple).)*?$|$))(?=.*?(?:simple|complex))(?=(?:(?!complex).)*?(?:(?:complex)(?:(?!complex).)*?$|$)).*?$`

Make sure that the expression is in multi line mode in whatever you are using to implement this (most of the time the default is multi line mode).

Matches:

```html
using simple with complex here
eggs are both complex and simple all at once
simple
complex
some simple things
some complex things
```

Does not match:

```html
this is irrelevant 
eggs are both complex and simple all at once said simple simon
simple simple
complex complex
```

The expression can be broken down into three requirements:

- `(?=.*?(?:simple|complex))` The line must contain either 'simple' or 'complex'
- `(?=(?:(?!simple).)*?(?:(?:simple)(?:(?!simple).)*?$|$))` The line can only have one or no occurrence of simple
- `(?=(?:(?!complex).)*?(?:(?:complex)(?:(?!complex).)*?$|$))` The line can only have one or no occurrence of complex

Comment: This appears overly complicated. `^(?!.*simple.*simple|.*complex.*complex).*(simple|complex).*` will do the same.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, much easier to read and much more efficient